# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, mvc

При отправке формы происходит ошибка(Даже, если не выбран файл). При отсутствии input type="file" ошибки не возникает

[image: Возникающая ошибка при нажатии на submit]
Задача- загрузить фото при помощи формы, и передать фото контроллеру.
Представление:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patronymic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Patronymic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patronymic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id ="Photo" name="Photo" accept="image/*" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="hidden" name="IdRole" id="IdRole" value="6"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" id="test" onclick="func()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Действие контроллера:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(User u, HttpPostedFileBase Photo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DataBaseContext context = new DataBaseContext())
                {
                    if (Photo != null)
                    {
                        byte[] imageData = null;
                        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Photo.InputStream))
                        {
                            imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Photo.ContentLength);
                        }
                        u.Photo = imageData;
                    }                     
                    context.Users.Add(u);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                Session["currentUser"] = u;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Данные введены некорректно!";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: продублируйте ошибку текстом, тут не у всех есть лупы

Answer (score 0):

```
[Bind(Exclude="Photo")]
public class User 
{
  ...
}
```

или

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude="Photo")]User u, HttpPostedFileBase Photo)
{
  ...
}
```

или

```
<input type="file" id ="userPhoto" name="userPhoto" accept="image/*" />

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(User u, HttpPostedFileBase userPhoto)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Большое большое! Помогло!